# unfortunately app has stopped android

Tags: android

My application is running fine on android version 2.3.7 but when i run it on android 4.2 it says unfortunately app has stopped

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.radaee.reader"

    android:versionCode="1"

    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartApp">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.radaee.reader.StartApp" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:minSdkVersion="4" android:maxSdkVersion="17"/>
</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 02-09 13:42:08.241   609:  609 E/StrictMode ]
?:??: W/?(?): null
?:??: W/?(?): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd52a8 that was originally bound here
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
?:??: W/?(?): [ 02-09 13:42:08.241   290:  501 W/ActivityManager ]
?:??: W/?(?): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@415d29b8
?:??: W/?(?): [ 02-09 13:42:21.891   392:  392 W/Trace    ]
?:??: W/?(?): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
?:??: W/?(?): [ 02-09 13:42:21.911   392:  392 W/Trace    ]
?:??: W/?(?): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Can  anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: post the logcat? What error is crashing the app

Comment: Whate happens here: ServiceProxy.java:157

Answer (score -1):

change you activity name like this in manifest.xml and try

```
android:name=".SplashScreen"
```

change to

```
 android:name="com.radaee.reader.SplashScreen"
```

Comment: Nope: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm

Comment: by doing this it says Failed to install PDFReader.apk on device 'emulator-5556!
[2013-02-09 17:50:34 - PDFReader] (null)
[2013-02-09 17:50:34 - PDFReader] Launch canceled!